Hp T520 Flexible Series Tc
I installed ThinPro 7.0.0.1 os on HP T52, installation went well and now the computer is going directly to the grub prompt immediately on start-up
How can I solve this problem?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Okay,
I tried to reset my desktop Hp T50, which was running on win 10 and it only stopped in 3% and start flashing non-stop.
I tried  to install a fresh win 10 but was not going through, i tried to install win 10 IoT but doesn't help, i tried many OS from HP Thinupdate tool and only ThinPro 7.1.0 worked.
There is a step whereby it says remove the usb and press enter then i did that, the desktop went off and reboot itself and what come on the screen is "GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.28-hp1
I tried the many steps to solve this but am getting lost since its not show Hd0,gpt
I used
Grub>ls then enter
(hd0) (hd0, msdos2) (hd0) (hd0, msdos1)
